# why if null function in mysql returns value as string instead of integer

Tags: mysql, sql

176. Second Highest Salary   leetcode problem

Input:

```
Employee table:
+----+--------+
| id | salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
| 200                 |
+---------------------+


select IFNULL((select max(salary) 
from employee 
where salary < (select max(salary) from employee)),'null') as SecondhighestSalary;
```

ouput as

Output

```
{"headers": ["SecondhighestSalary"], "values": [["200"]]}
```

Expected

```
{"headers": ["SecondHighestSalary"], "values": [[200]]}
```

why 200 is showing as string in output

Comment: How did you make that JSON from the output of that query?

Comment: `'null'` is a string and not equivalent to `NULL`.

Comment: `The default return type of IFNULL(expr1,expr2) is the more "general" of the two expressions, in the order STRING, REAL, or INTEGER.`, see [Flow Control Functions :: IFNULL(expr1,expr2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull). Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hpJO2iQB).

Comment: There is a difference between `NULL` (no value) and `'null'` (a string containing "null").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the two comments into a formal answer.

**'null'** is not the same as **NULL**.  Since one argument is numeric and the other string, **IFNULL** returns the more generic value, ie the string.

> The default return type of IFNULL(expr1,expr2) is the more “general” of the two expressions, in the order STRING, REAL, or INTEGER.

from [MySQL Doc 8,0 Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Consider using some known integer value instead of a string "null", either a very large value or -1 (as appropriate to our business logic).  Then deal with it appropriately when displaying.